# Make PyCharm use a new shell terminal for script output?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

When launching a script from PyCharm, either for simple running or debugging, how can I make it open up a dedicate shell terminal instead of using PyCharm's built in Output window? I working on some terminal text based gui apps, and the built in output window is not all suitable for that.